# When should a new container be created in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to store data of different structures on Azure CosmosDB. I know that a container can store different types of data. In production they're being differentiated by assigning them different "type" property.

As I was watching the [best practices video](https://youtu.be/bQBeTeYUrR8?t=1067): I noticed that there are two containers presented (timestamp: 17:47): [image: Two containers in CosmosDB]

The first one, *users*, has only one data types, while the second one, *posts*, includes two types of content: posts and comments.

1. When would it be advisable to create a new container instead of adding data of different type to the one already created?
2. Paraphrasing the question a bit: since a container can store various data types, why not put *users*, *posts* and *comments* from the screen above in just one container?

Comment: `The limit for the amount of data stored in one container is 20 GB` - This is not correct. 20GB limit is for the maximum amount of data that can be stored in a single logical partition.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I removed the info from the question. For anyone needing this information: there is no storage limit per container (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#provisioned-throughput).

Comment: What did you end up doing in your situation?

Answer (score 3):

Data can be stored in the same container when it shares the same partition key and is accessed together.

You can't put users, posts and comments in the same container because users is partitioned on id, (essentially the user id) and posts is partitioned on postId.

Comment: I see two solutions:
1. The one presented on the screen above (two containers),
2. One container for all documents (users, posts and comments). They could have IDs in a form of GUIDs. They would be discerned by the `type` property (`user`, `post`, or `comment`).

If the second one is incorrect, could you please explain why? If not, my goal is to find pros and cons of both design proposals.

Comment: The second one is incorrect because to get a post and all its comments you would need to make two requests. One to the post container and one to the comment container.. When designing for a NoSQL database the objective is to reduce the number of requests as much as possible and model and store the data how the application uses it. There is a more recent version of this presentation we did in 2019 that may help explain these concepts better. Recommend watching this one. https://youtu.be/utdxvAhIlcY There is also a GitHub repository mentioned at the end of this talk that has a deck and demos.